# C# Check if a slot of an array is filled with a class object

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I try to "tick" every object in an array called "knownSolarSystems" but because of the definition every array slot is set.
(At least it's not empty lels)

```
CSolarSystem[] knownSolarSystems;
public void Start () {
    knownSolarSystems = new CSolarSystem[10];
    knownSolarSystems[0] = new CSolarSystem();
}
```

Above I created an object of the CSolarSystem class which I pasted in the first (0th?) slot of the array. (knownSolarSystems[0])

But even if I just have 1 object the foreach loop continues 10 times which is giving me errors because it tries to access a few objects which aren't defined yet.

This is the foreach loop:

```
foreach(CSolarSystem solarSystem in knownSolarSystems) {
    solarSystem.Update();
}
```

And this is the error:

```
NullReferenecException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object CUniverse.Update()
```

So is there a method to "skip" those slots which aren't filled?

With best regards, deSpeach

Comment: In addition to using `Where` to skip `null` values, do you really need to initialize this as an array of length 10? Could you just use a `List<CSolarSystem>` instead?

Comment: I wanted to but I don't know how to use them effectively so I use Arrays

Comment: You should really use a List<T> where T is you CSolarSystem. This removes the need to know before hand how many objects you handle (Of course if you know how many objects are present in the solar system you could still use an array and post your findings at http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/  :-)

Comment: The biggest issue with Lists I had is that I can't really access the List I want to... I didn't know for example how I can handle those List as easy as I can handle an array. (For example with an array:
example[1] = 5; but with a list: example.add(20); But if I add another slot how can I access to the slot before? That's why I used arrays

Comment: _"But if I add another slot how can I access to the slot before? "_ You can access a list in the same way as an array, via index, for example: `CSolarSystem last = knownSolarSystems[knownSolarSystems.Count-1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is there a method to "skip" those slots which aren't filled?

You could simply check if it's still not initialized (`null`):

```
foreach(CSolarSystem solarSystem in knownSolarSystems.Where(s => s != null)) {
    solarSystem.Update();
}
```

Note that you need to add `using System.Linq` at the top of the file.

Another way is to use a `List<T>` instead of an array which can be increased:

```
List<CSolarSystem> knownSolarSystems = new List<CSolarSystem>();

public void Start () {
    knownSolarSystems.Add(new CSolarSystem());
}
```

Comment: It gives me the error, that there is no definition of "Where"

Comment: You need to add the `using System.Linq`, i've edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) to eliminate *null* values:

```
foreach(CSolarSystem solarSystem in knownSolarSystems.Where(x => x != null))
{
   solarSystem.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course: check if a slot is filled, and if it isn't then skip it.

```
foreach(CSolarSystem solarSystem in knownSolarSystems) {
    if (solarSystem == null) continue;
    solarSystem.Update();
}
```

The `null` test can also be moved around as the LINQ versions other people posted show.

Comment: But this one skips also the filled arrays D: